# Retrieve value for On/Off switch

Tags: php, html, css, api

I'm still new to web development and API so forgive me. So I have on/off button switch, which I am unsure how to make the default of the switch on or off depending on the values returned. The values are 1 for true and 0 for false.

To retrieve the value I would need to call `<?php $resultMemberInfo['allowNotification']?>`, which currently is returning the value '1', but how do I go about implementing it in my switch so that it is able to display what is called from the backend?

Switch.php

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
 <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
      <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
         <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
         <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
      </label>
</div>
```

css

```
.onoffswitch {
    position: relative; width: 90px; float: left;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "ON";
    value: '1';
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #34A7C1; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "OFF";
    value: '0';
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 18px; margin: 6px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 56px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s; 
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: Use this **$("input[type='checkbox']").val();**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make onoff switch dynamic like:

Swtich.php

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
   <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" <?php echo $resultMemberInfo['allowNotification'] == '1'?'checked':''; ?>>
   <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
     <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
     <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
   </label>
</div>
```